# show Apple ID or Email on iMessage

Tags: security, messages, apple-id, ios, privacy

How can you change the phone Nr. from showing up on iMessage? I'd rather have it changed to my email or Apple ID instead.

Comment: Your Apple ID **is** your email address.

Comment: @tubedogg It is possible to have a primary email address that is different from your apple ID, in addition to alternate emails.

Comment: @NReilingh By definition an Apple ID is an email address. Whether it is your primary email or not, it is your email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings app > Messages > Send & Receive, and at the bottom under "Start New Conversations From" change it to your preferred option. Your email address and phone number will both appear there.